# How do I copy specific set of files in one directory structure to another?

Tags: linux, cygwin, file-transfer, file-management

Say I've got a directory structure somewhat like this:

```
view
 |
 +--- 0001
 |
 +--- 231
 |
 +--- e2341
 |
 ... and so on
```

My problem is that I want to copy a set of files that have the same name (such as file_001.jpg) to another place that has an identical directory structure, i.e. it's a mirror. Is there a way to copy files of a specific name pattern from one directory structure to another?

I tried something along the lines with…

```
cp -R */file_001.jpg /destination_folder
```

…but all I get is the following error

```
cp: cannot stat `file_001.jpg': No such file or directory
```

I guess I have to pipe in the file names somehow, anyone got any good idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **find** combined with the passthrough feature of **cpio** for that.  Something like this:

```
find old_dir -name "file_001.jpg" -print | cpio -pd new_dir
```

The `-p` flag on cpio triggers passthrough mode, which effectively just copies files from their original location to `new_dir`.  The `-d` flag creates all the necessary directories, so you'll have the same heirarchy under `new_dir` as you had under `old_dir` (at least, so far as directories containing `file_001.jpg` are concerned).